Renew FreeIPA certs when existing cert already expired
I have FreeIPA on Rocky 8. I installed custom certs from LetsEncrypt using the command
ipa-cacert-manage -p DM_PASSWORD -n NICKNAME -t C,, install ca.crt
ipa-certupdate
ipa-server-certinstall -w -d /ssl/key.pem /ssl/fullchain.pem

The certificate expired on June 15th.  The new LE certificate I have is only valid starting July 2nd.  If I run ipa-server-certinstall at current, it fails because the existing certificate is expired.  If I run it after setting my date to June 14th, it fails because the new certificate isn't valid until July.
Is there a way to force install the certificate?  I tried just copying them to /var/lib/ipa/{certs,private} and that worked for the web interface (although I still can't login), but not for the ipa command and pki-tomcat still fails to start.
Note that the LE CA cert being used is valid until 2025 so that isn't an issue.

When dealing with expired FreeIPA certificates and attempting to renew them using Let's Encrypt certificates, the key challenge is the date validation both from the expired certificate and the new certificate.
Become root and follow these steps:
Make sure you have a backup of your current configuration and certificates before making any changes.
tar czf /root/ipa-backup-$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.gz /etc/ipa /var/lib/ipa /etc/httpd /etc/pki

You can use the --force option with the ipa-server-certinstall command to bypass the date validity checks.
ipa-server-certinstall -w -d /ssl/key.pem /ssl/fullchain.pem --force

After installing the new certificates, restart FreeIPA and related services to apply the changes.
ipa-certupdate
ipactl restart

That should do it! But I would automate certificate renewal using Certbot and Certmonger to prevent future expiration issues.
(replace some values to reflect your system)
Install Certbot:
dnf install certbot

Request a new certificate from Let's Encrypt:
certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns -d yourdomain.com

Create a script to handle the renewal process. Save this script as /usr/local/bin/renew_cert.sh and make it executable.
#!/bin/bash
certbot renew --quiet
ipa-server-certinstall -w -d /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem --force
ipactl restart

Then:
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/renew_cert.sh

Now,configure Certmonger:
ipa-getcert request -d /etc/httpd/alias -n Server-Cert -N "CN=yourdomain.com,O=Your Organization" -K HTTP/yourdomain.com@YOURREALM -k /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem -f /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem -C "/usr/local/bin/renew_cert.sh"

After Certmonger renews the certificate, update FreeIPA.
ipa-server-certinstall -w -d /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem --force

Restart FreeIPA services:
ipa-certupdate
ipactl restart

If any command fails, check the respective log files for detailed error messages:
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
tail -f /var/log/pki/pki-tomcat/ca/debug
tail -f /var/log/ipa/ipareplica-install.log

Verify that the new certificate and key are properly formatted and valid:
openssl x509 -in /ssl/fullchain.pem -noout -text
openssl rsa -in /ssl/key.pem -check

Good luck!

It says the --force option doesnt exist on ipa-server-certinstall, so I can't bypass the date check.  I should mention that I'm on FreeIPA 4.9.12

I solved the issue.
The kerberos certificate was valid for a 2 year span.  I found the location of it using ipa-getcert list.
I then ran
ipa-server-certinstall -w -d /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.key /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.crt --dirman-password=PASSWORD

to set the cert to one that's now valid according to the FreeIPA CA.
Now that I have a valid cert, I can install the LE certificate.  I need to reinstall the CA to get it working though.
ipa-cacert-manage -p PASWORD -n letsencrypt -t C,, install ca.pem
ipa-certupdate
ipa-server-certinstall -w -d /ssl/mysite.com/key.pem /ssl/mysite.com/fullchain.pem --dirman-password=PASSWORD
ipactl restart

And all is good!
